# change entityform value via function before save

Tags: entities

I have an entityform with a field call "IP" (field_ip is its machine name). Now I need to set a value before that the entityform is saved. I have thinked to use hook_entity_presave() in this way:

```
function mymodule_entity_presave($entity, $type) {
      if ($type == 'entityform') {
        if ($entity->is_new === true || 1==1) {
          $entity->field_ip = array('LANGUAGE_NONE' => array(0 => array('value' => $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],'format' => '','safe_value' => $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])));
          $entity->original->field_ip = $entity->field_ip;   //Try this, too.
        };
      }
    }
```

(1==1 is only for test/debug).

Via "devel" module I can see that the new value of field_ip is correctly set, but when I see the new version of the entityform entry (after the save action) I see the default value of that field and not my new value.
And infact if I re-edit the same entyform (id) I see the old value and not the new one. Where is my error ?

Comment: What type of field is `field_ip`?

Comment: I tried something similar to this, and it's working fine with a text field in `entityform`. If `field_ip` is a Text field, you only need to assign its 'value' (text fields do not have 'format' or 'safe_value' properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I now see what the problem is. LANGUAGE_NONE should not have quotes around it. It's a constant. Been there, done that. :)

Comment: Thanks. I have view and review my function more and more times but I have never see quotes around LANGUAGE_NONE.